# How to load PHPExcel inside a library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, phpexcel

somewhen back i followed [this](http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework) tutorial to implement PHPExcel in CI.

Now everything worked fine with that snippet but i tried creating my library that loads the PHPExcel and encoutred a problem.

I've created a CI instance :

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('excel');
```

Which works great and i am building my excel file but in the metnioned tutorial, to save it the following command is being used :

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($CI->excel, 'Excel2007');
```

Which worked great when i used it inside the controller, but in a library i get an error of :
`Fatal error: Class 'XMLWriter' not found in /path/to/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Shared/XMLWriter.php on line 44`

Now i guess it has something to do with the way this is being called, can anyone tell me how can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i solved it, the problem was i havn't checked my server has the [requirements](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Requirements) of PHPExcel, and i'm missing php_xml.
When i got it to work i worked on localhost (XAMPP) which did have those extensions enabled.

Answer (score 1):

you have not installed xml, just ***run below command in terminal***

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

and restart your apache2.